# jQuery: Set form input value to json data

Tags: jquery, json, django, forms

I am trying to insert an instance ID which I am receiving via JSON into a form input.

```
function assignCategoryValue()
{
    var userInput = $("#input_transaction_category").val();
    var formOptions = document.getElementById("id_transaction_category").options;

    for(var i=1;i<formOptions.length;i++)
    {
        if(formOptions[i].text == userInput)
        {
            // This works.
            $("#id_transaction_category").val(formOptions[i].value);
            console.log(formOptions[i].value);
            return false;
        }
    }

    alert("Doesn't exist, creating.");
    $.ajaxSetup({async: false});
    var postdata = { 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}' }
    $.post("create_category/"+userInput+'/', postdata, function( data ){
      for(var key in data)
      if (data.hasOwnProperty(key))
        var foo = data[key];
        // The console prints out the value I want.
        console.log(foo);
        $("#id_transaction_category").val(foo);
        // Yet after I set the value, the console prints a blank line.
        console.log($("#id_transaction_category").val()); 
        return false;
    });
}
```

According to the console the JSON has the value I want but I am having troubles inserting it into my form.

The JSON which is sent by the $.post is like this:

```
data = json.dumps({"category_id" : category_id})
print data

{"category_id": 178} // from server console
```

The JSON which is received by the $.post is like this:

```
$.post("create_category/"+userInput+'/', postdata, function( data ){
console.log(data);
Object {category_id: 180} // From crhome console

var foo = data[key];
console.log(foo);
180 // From chrome console
```

The input I am trying to fill:

```
<select id="id_transaction_category" name="transaction_category">
  <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
  <option value="1">Travel</option>
  <option value="2">New</option>
  <option value="3">test</option>
  .
  .
  .
  <option value="191">nfaha</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Please check this id "id_transaction_category" may be duplicated it your page.

Comment: @MMK I just have it once.

Comment: Are you sure that your jQuery selector are valid? Use
`console.log($("#id_transaction_category").lenght)` to check if there are results for your query. Also post here your HTML portion of code that contains this input.

Comment: Is `#id_transaction_category` a form input?

Comment: @EliasSoares I think so.

The create method gets called if an instance of the model does not already exist. This is the method which gets ran (and works) before a creation happens.

for(var i=1;i<formOptions.length;i++)
{
if(formOptions[i].text == userInput)
{
   $("#id_transaction_category").val(formOptions[i].value);
console.log(formOptions[i].value);
return false;
}
}`

Comment: @RezaOwliaei Yes, its a form input

Comment: Give us a sample of your json please.

Answer (score 0):

Some reasons ending to such problem:

1. There is no `#id_transaction_category` element in your document.
2. You can set value of form elements using `.val()`, such as input. Make sure about the element you pointing with `#id_transaction_category` selector.
3. Make sure about all Values in your iteration. You should expect the value of #id_transaction_category to be set with last `data[key]`

Comment: Owilaei I added alot more information to my question, perhaps it will be more obvious now.

Comment: try `$("#id_transaction_category").val(foo.category_id)`

Comment: Still seeing blanks in my console :(

Likewise with foo.value

Comment: Do one test, instead of `foo`, fill the input val with an static string such as `test` and check the console log.

Comment: The console is giving a null, instead of nothing.

Comment: Giving it a digit, 8, gave 8 in the console

Comment: Well, probably the problem is your selector. Please show the html code of the input element.

Comment: I gave it .val("test") and the console said it was null. I gave it .val(8) and the console said 8. The input element is: <td style="display: none"> {{ transaction_form.transaction_category }} </td>

Comment: Ok, right click on the page and view source, and check if you are generating many `td`, which wraps `<input id = "id_transaction_category" \>`.

Comment: If it's possible please show two generated td tags from view source option.

Comment: Added it to my question. Thank you for your time so far!

Comment: In fact you are assigning a value to a select element not an input. If you set a select.val("foo"), option "foo" (if there is any) would be the selected one. What are you about to do? Are you trying to insert a new option to your select, or select an option by its' value?

Comment: Ahh.. I realise now that using the select is not a solution here. I think i need to create a custom form checker server-side and give it an input with a number in it. The reason being that the selector does not want any value outside its bounds

Comment: You can use `jquery.data` to store custom data on any dom element. `val` would be a solution if there was a `<input type="hidden"\>` to store a value.